# Reducers and immutability in ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

When creating a reducer function in ngrx, everywhere I read says that I should return a copy of the original/previous state. Either by using spread operators or by using a library or tricks like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))`.

But I found one catch there and I couldn't find anyone talking about it.
The last state returned in a reducer is the state that's going to be shared with all current subscribers and with future subscribers too.
That means that all components that use a certain store will see the same state object.

That also means that if any value in the state is changed in one component (without dispatching an action), the store will actually have the value modified, but the other components won't be notified.
What's the point in returning a copy of the current state if it's going to be shared everywhere?

The word immutable is used all the time, but that state is not immutable at all, because the store returns its own inner object, and not a copy of that.

I understand if the immutable part is a concept that needs to be followed by the developer. But then, the copy of the original object/values needs to be done in the component that uses it. Returning a shallow or deep copy from the reducer seems to be just waste of processing power and memory.

Comment: You are not supposed to mutate the state from your components. To make sure of that you can use something like ngrx-store-freeze that'll throw an error if you do.

Comment: Ok, but then what's the point of making the reducer return copies?
If components shouldn't change the value of the store directly, the reducer can always manipulate the same state object, it doesn't make sense to me to add overhead and code complexity.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer to your question has been answered plenty of time if you dig a little bit. " it doesn't make sense to me to add overhead and code complexity" it's probably because you don't need a Redux pattern for now.

Comment: By code complexity and overhead I don't mean redux itself, I'm just studying it. I mean making the reducer return copies, that's what doesn't make sense to me, just as explained in my original question and in my reply here.
Everywhere I read they say that you should return copies to make it immutable, but that doesn't make it immutable, that's my point.

Comment: You are responsible for the immutability. It's the contract that you make when using Redux. The state must be manipulated only from the reducers and in an immutable way. "but that doesn't make it immutable". No! No magic here. It you, whom have to ensure the immutability.

Comment: I understand. But that's the whole point: if you are responsible for not changing the store from outside the reducers, it doesn't look like there is any advantage in returning copies of the state from the reducers.

Comment: Please read redux documentation. Ngrx works with the same principles and not understanding redux before using ngrx will only make it harder... The redux documentation is very well written :)

Comment: You create a "new" state in order to create a new reference to the state. Doing this has the benefit that your selectors can be memoized and that you can change the change detection strategy to `OnPush`.

Comment: +1 to what @timdeschryver said. That's the main goal of returning a copy. Because returning a new object (instead of mutating it) you are representing a change on an object property by also changing the reference to that object. That allows you to use the (OnPush) Change Detection Strategy on your whole application, dramatically increasing its performance.
Anyway, I do agree with you. The ngrx team should enforce the state immutability by freezing the state so that no one can mistakenly mutate it.

Comment: Another point here is the feature of time traveling debugging. Because each action returns a new state (instead of mutating the previous one) ngrx can keep a record of all the previous states for debugging purposes. That wouldn't be possible if you were mutating the same object in memory. With this feature, tracking bugs and understanding how the app behaves is much easier.

Answer (score 9):

I'll try and answer.

A reducer in pesudocode looks like this:

```
myReducer(state, action) {

  switch(action) {

    case ACTION_1:
      return {...state, prop: action.payload}

    case ACTION_2:
      const newState = _.cloneDeep(state)
      newState.prop = action.payload
      return newState

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In case ACTION_1 you are not mutating state. The spread operator creates a new object with a new reference and the new reference is what is needed to signal a change.

In case ACTION_2 you are cloning the state. You mutate the cloned state and return it. Because the cloned state has a new object reference it signals a change has been made and everyone is happy.

In the default scenario, any other action (e.g. ACTION_3) is ignored and the original state is returned signifying that state has not changed. The object reference has not changed and thus "no change" is signalled (this is why it is important not to mutate the original state).

When an action is fired off, the action is passed to EVERY reducer. And thus, reducers that don't want to modify their associated piece of state can ignore the action by relying on the default case statement.

A single action can, and often does, trigger state changes in multiple reducers.

If the returned object reference has changed, it will trigger any related RxJS state subscriptions for the particular piece of state in question. Which subscriptions are triggered can be minimised using some good ngrx selectors.

PS There's a great library called ngrx-store-freeze which will enforce the "no mutation" principle. It will throw an error early if you mutate state. This helps to avoid hard to track down bugs. Hook into store freeze with a meta reducer.

PPS The whole purpose of using the object reference to determine change is because it is much faster to check an object reference than it is to check every value on an object to see if it has changed. This is why immutability is so relevant.

Comment: Just for the record: I tested returning always the same state object and the subscribers do get notified.

Comment: OK then I suggest you use ngrx selectors which have more intelligence.

Comment: Are you familiar with selectors? If not I'll dump some example code for you.

Comment: the big question is when to use the spread operator and when cloneDeep.
as we know, the spread operator is a shallow copy. it will include a reference to the existing inner objects/arrays of the original state.
so if some component relies on an array/object which is a property of the state, it will not be notified of a change.
sometimes this is the needed behavior, sometimes it is not...

Comment: I'm new to Redux/ngrx. You say >> A single action can, and often does, trigger state changes in multiple reducers. << So, with a chain `Action -> Reducers -> Views`, if two reducers both subscribe to the same action and both return new copies of the state, which one "wins"? Or are they merged again?

Comment: To answer my own question, if I understand [the Redux FAQ](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#how-does-redux-use-shallow-equality-checking) correctly, the idea is that each reducer looks after its own slice/domain of state, and redux will then merge the changed slices. So, this works as long as there are no two reducers subscribing to the same action manipulating the same slice.

Comment: there is nothing to prevent 2 reducers listening for the same action - an action passes through all reducers for this reason